# How to pass a list of file names to xargs after checking if the file exists?

Tags: files, osx, xargs

I have a command (`command1`) that returns a list of file names like below

```
/consumer/a.txt
/consumer/b.txt
/consumer/doesnotexist.txt
```

When I pipe the output like `command1 | xargs command2` `command2` throws exception if one of the files does not exist.

How do I remove non-existant files before piping it to `command2`? I am expecting something in the lines of

`command1 | xargs remove_nonexistant_files | xargs command2`

`command2` should receive

```
/consumer/a.txt
/consumer/b.txt
```

as input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
command1 |
xargs sh -c 'for p do [ -f "$p" ] && printf "%s\n" "$p"; done' sh |
xargs command 2
```

The extra bit in the middle is a another `xargs` invocation of a short script that basically just loops over its given command line arguments and prints the pathnames that correspond to existing regular files (or symbolic links to regular files).  These existing pathnames are then passed on to the last part of the pipeline.

This assumes that all pathnames are free from embedded newlines, spaces and tabs.

Comment: _free from embedded newlines_... and space, tab (and other spacing characters with some implementations) and single quote, double quote and backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `command1` outputs the list in the format expected by `xargs`, you could define:

```
existing_plain_readable_files_only() {
  perl -le "for (@ARGV) {
    if (-f && -r) {s/'/'\\\\''/g; print qq('\$_')}
  }" -- "$@"
}
```

And use it as:

```
command1 | xargs existing_plain_readable_files_only | xargs command2
```

Here, we use `perl`'s `-f` operator for *regular* files only (not directories, devices, pipes...) and `-r` for those that are *readable* by the user (assuming `command2` will want to read them), and we use single-quote quoting except for the single quote characters themselves which is escaped with `\`.

That's a kind of quoting that is supported by both `xargs` and the shell, which means you can also use that function to process shell arrays containing arbitrary lists of files:

```
eval "array2=($(existing_plain_readable_files_only "${array1[@]}"))"
```

(here assuming `ksh93`, `zsh`, `bash`, `mksh` or `yash` shells).